# Access notifiers from Bluetooth connection initialised in another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have two activities in an Android app; FirstActivity and SecondActivity. FirstActivity initialises a Bluetooth Low Energy connection as required to communicate with a device. I also wish to use that same connection from SecondActivity, rather than reinitialising a connection.

Reading around Stack Overflow, I hear that I can pass the BluetoothDevice variable (containing a reference to the connected device) to SecondActivity by storing it into a class that extends Application, and then recalling it from SecondActivity. I have been able to do this and verified it by reading the device name of the incoming variable. I need to be able to change values based on notifications from the device in SecondActivity.

In FirstActivity, I do this by using a BluetoothGattCallback which moves through state machine-styled code to systematically initialise each device sensor, from this tutorial - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1y4tEHDwk0&feature=player_detailpage#t=241), [code](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGatt). After initialisation is complete, it calls the onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic) method, within the callback, whenever a previously specified characteristic is changed.

In order to access notifiers from the device in SecondActivity, do I need to set up another BluetoothGattCallback so that I can use onCharacteristicChanged, or is there a way to interface with the callback from FirstActivity (which is still in the background when SecondActivity is in focus)?
I have tried also passing BluetoothGatt and BluetoothGattCallback variables along with BluetoothDevice, but as I am fairly new to Android (and moreso to Bluetooth), I will admit it has been a trial-and-error process. I am also still getting my head around how the Callback is first called, so I apologise in advance if I'm missing something simple. All advice is appreciated!

Comment: It might be better to manage the connection in a service and communicate to the activities via a broadcast listener.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli - I've been reading up on Services and Broadcasts (LocalBroadcastManager in particular) and I just want to run this by you to make sure I have the roughly the right idea.
- When the user want to connect to a device, start the service to set up the connection.
- When a characteristic is updated, send some kind of indication back to the Activity through the Broadcaster (With a Listener to broadcaster?)
- If the Activity in focus is changed, send some kind of indication to the Service so it knows what data is should sent for which Activity.

Comment: Sounds good. However the cool thing about broadcasters is you dont have to notify the service that the activity changed. Just unregister when you leave focus and register in focus. Also keep in mind that which ever thread does the broadcasting with match the resulting onreceive call. So if you are doing any ui updates make sure to use the mainthread. Most bluetooth callbacks are from a binder thread. The examples of bt callbacks are littered with bad handling of callbacks in this way